# FormatMessage returns 0 for d3d11 error. How can I get error description for d3d11 errors?

Tags: c++, direct3d

I'm trying to create a debug macro for d3d11 calls. Here is how it looks:

```cpp
#define ERROR_MSG(DESC, MSG, CODE)\
        MessageBox(nullptr, MSG, DESC, MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);\
        exit(CODE);             

#define ASSER_D3D11_CALL(CALL)\
        {\
            DWORD msg = HRESULT_CODE(CALL);\
            if(msg != 0)\
            {\
                LPSTR str = nullptr;\
                if(0 == FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE |  FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,\
                                    NULL,\
                                    msg,\
                                    LANG_ENGLISH,\
                                    str,\
                                    32,\
                                    nullptr))\
                {\
                    ERROR_MSG("Unknown Error", str, msg);\
                }\
                ERROR_MSG("Error", str, msg);\
            }\
        }
```

When I try simulating an error, I don't get any message, FormatMessage() returns 0. Here is the code that triggers the error. I tried it on other cases as well.

```cpp
DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC d_SwapChain{ 0 };
    ... some setup that works...
    d_SwapChain.OutputWindow = wnd.m_hwnd + 1; // adding 1 here causes error
    ... 

    // Create device and buffers
    ASSER_D3D11_CALL(D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(...correctly configured stuff...));
```

What can I do to get an error message?

Answer (score 0):

Which operating system are you using? The Direct3D HRESULT values were not added to `FormatMessage` until Windows 8, so on Windows 7 you won't get any results.

See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/wheres-dxerr-lib/) for an open source version of `DXERR.LIB` which was intended to do this.